# What is more efficient? (SP PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, commit

I have a stored procedure which performs some transactions (insert / update) and want to know which of these two options run **"COMMIT"** more efficiently:

**OPTION 1:**

```
     BEGIN        
          OPEN myCursor;
            LOOP               
                FETCH myCursor INTO AUX_ID, AUX_VAR1, AUX_VAR2;
                  EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND;   

                      SELECT count(*) INTO myCount   FROM myTable    WHERE code = AUX_ID;

                      IF myCount > 0 THEN
                          UPDATE myTable
                          SET VAR1 = AUX_VAR1, VAR2 = AUX_VAR2
                          WHERE code = AUX_ID_BD;
                          COMMIT;
                      ELSE
                          INSERT INTO myTable(code, VAR1, VAR2)
                          VALUES(AUX_ID, AUX_VAR1, AUX_VAR2)
                          COMMIT;
                      END IF;              
            END LOOP;
          CLOSE myCursor;    
     END;
```

---

OR **OPTION 2:**

```
          BEGIN        
          OPEN myCursor;
            LOOP               
                FETCH myCursor INTO AUX_ID, AUX_VAR1, AUX_VAR2;
                  EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND;   

                      SELECT count(*) INTO myCount   FROM myTable    WHERE code = AUX_ID;

                      IF myCount > 0 THEN
                          UPDATE myTable
                          SET VAR1 = AUX_VAR1, VAR2 = AUX_VAR2
                          WHERE code = AUX_ID_BD;
                      ELSE
                          INSERT INTO myTable(code, VAR1, VAR2)
                          VALUES(AUX_ID, AUX_VAR1, AUX_VAR2)
                      END IF;              
            END LOOP;
            COMMIT;
          CLOSE myCursor;    
     END;
```

it's okay? or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think you will see any performance enhancement with either but you may be messing with transactional independence with option 2. What if you needed to rollback the first update statement?

Comment: You can go through this [lengthy discussion in Asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022)! A famous question though.. My personal opinion would be, if Data is real huge, `COMMIT` in batches of reasonable size. Otherwise, if you ever want to rollback something, go for commit per insert..

Comment: Can't all of this be solved by using a single [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement instead ? Or do I missed something ?

Comment: And even if it can't be simplified to a single `merge` statement, depending on the nature of the cursor, the `select count(*)... if ... etc.` could be a merge statement.

Comment: The whole code can be replaced with a single `MERGE` statement. Also you should close the cursor before you commit. It is not important in this case, but it is a good practice - do not fetch cursor across the commits (unless it is not 100% necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #2 is definitely more efficient, although it's hard to tell if it will be noticeable in your case.

Every `COMMIT` requires a small amount of physical I/O; Oracle must ensure all the data is written to disk, the system change number (SCN) is written to disk, and there are probably other consistency checks I'm not aware of.  In practice, it takes a huge number of `COMMIT`s from multiple users to significantly slow down a database.  When that happens you may see unusual wait events involving REDO, control files, etc.

Before a `COMMIT` is issued, Oracle can make the changes in memory or asynchronously.  This may allow the performance to be [equivalent to an in-memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627700/409172).

---

An even better option is to avoid the issue entirely by using a single `MERGE` statement, as Sylvain Leroux suggested.  If the processing must be done in PL/SQL, at least replace the OPEN/FETCH cursor syntax with a simpler cursor FOR-loop.  A cursor FOR-loop will automatically bulk collect data, significantly improving read performance.

Comment: Thank you all, but I have one last question.. about merge sentence I read is not recommended for bulk-data.
is that true?

Comment: I disagree with that statement.  In some ways a `MERGE` is better for bulk data.  For example, it supports hash joins whereas `UPDATE` only supports nested loops.  There are issues when running large DML statements, but I don't know of a reason to specifically avoid `MERGE`.

Comment: Even in my workplace, they claim Merge to be costlier(I don't know why exactly!). And we normally use PL/SQL  only for these delta updates/inserts.[This Analysis has a lot of more details](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I'm not a fan of that article.  I've seen it used to justify complex PL/SQL over simple SQL when the (confusing) results don't support that.  Appendix 2 practically admits the comparison between method 7 and 8 is unfair.  Comparing different methods with different DOPs is meaningless, and both 128 and 256 are probably too high for such a small workload anyway.  When the DOP is manually set, as it should be, the methods have the same performance.

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar if MERGE was costlier, why Oracle did on implement it the way how PL/SQL is doing the same task? Maybe it's performace depends on Oracle version, I recall there were some limitations in 10g

Comment: @ibre5041 I mentioned that, I even dont know the reason, just wanted to hear Jon's view on that. We have replication of data in 2 databases. so perhaps our DBA wanted to go for PL/SQL which can enable us COMMIT in batches. And in reality our jobs would not be as simple as Merge's syntax, it had multiple checks.