# Integration test with in memory db and spring jdbc

Tags: oracle, integration-testing, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

We have multiple oracle schema which we want to import in to somekind of inmemory db so that when we run our integration test we can use that db and run our tests faster.

Is there anyway we this can be achieved using something like HSQL db. We are using spring framework and it does support inmemory db.

Any link to some resource would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try [force full database caching mode](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#CNCPT94675), if you're using 12.1.0.2.  It's not exactly the same as a full in-memory database, but it should be closer.

```
alter database force full database caching;
```

In-memory database performance is over-rated anyway.  Oracle's "old-fashioned" asynchronous IO and caching often work just fine.  For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22558797/409172), accessing a temporary table (which is stored on disk) runs faster than an equivalent solution using in-memory data structures.  And I've seen a small Oracle database handle petabytes of IO with the "boring" old buffer cache.

Or when you say "run our tests faster", are you referring to a more agile database; one that can be controlled by an individual, instead of the typical monolithic Oracle database installed on a server?  I see that issue a lot, and there's no technical reason why Oracle can't be installed on your desktop.  But that can be a tough cultural battle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use HSQLDB for the purpose of unit testing - see [this post](https://tillias.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/unit-testing-and-integration-testing-using-junit-liquibase-hsqldb-hibernate-maven-and-spring-framework/) for more information on how to integrate with Spring.

Also, see [this list](http://hsqldb.org/web/usagelinks.html) as a good starting point for different usages of HSQLDB.