# Delete the same set of values from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to not have to repeat the same subquery over and over for all tables.

Example:

```
begin
    -- where subquery is quite complex and returns thousands of records of a single ID column
    delete from t1 where exists ( select 1 from subquery where t1.ID = subquery.ID );
    delete from t2 where exists ( select 1 from subquery where t2.ID = subquery.ID );
    delete from t3 where exists ( select 1 from subquery where t3.ID = subquery.ID );
end;
/
```

An alternative I've found is:

```
declare
  type id_table_type is table of table.column%type index by PLS_INTEGER
  ids id_table_type;
begin
  select ID
  bulk collect into ids
  from subquery;

  forall indx in 1 .. ids.COUNT
    delete from t1 where ID = ids(indx);

  forall indx in 1 .. ids.COUNT
    delete from t2 where ID = ids(indx);

  forall indx in 1 .. ids.COUNT
    delete from t3 where ID = ids(indx);
end;
/
```

What are your thoughts about this alternative? is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I believe `DELETE` in Oracle needs to have a single target table, so you can't join the tables together unfotunately.  That being said, it seems like the performance hog might be the really large subquery anyway, so the deletes may not be your biggest concern here.

Comment: SQL is always efficient than PL/SQL. For every SQL call inside PL/SQL there is an context switch between the two engines which is ultimately a performance overhead.

Comment: Your alternative solution is better if you want to do delete in batches, but, you need to catch exceptions. If at all one delete fails for some reasons otherwise. `Context switching`, yes it is an overhead. `FORALL` do a *bulk* binding which reduces that cost. [More on this from Steve](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html). Single DELETE statement is a no brainer thing. The DBMS takes care of stuffs, but it is a very debating topic. Both options has pros and cons. You can test out both options and  Examine the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary table, once, to hold the results of the subquery.

For each run, insert the results of the subquery into the temporary table.  The subquery only runs once and each delete is simple: `delete from mytable t where t.id in (select id from tmptable);`.

Truncate the table when finished.

Comment: what does "use the deletes against this temp table" mean?  the only way I can see working it would mean still using a subquery.

Comment: you would only have to run the subquery once  And you use this subquery to insert the target ID's into a temp table that will hold these ID;s.  Then you can run all the deletes you want without running the subquery for each delete command.   delete from mytable t where t.id in (select id from tmptable)

Comment: thnks Dave. It is better to use a temp table than a collection for the temporal storage of the thousand values?

Comment: No. It won't be efficient. moreover, you cannot go on creating temp tables in production environment. When you fetch the result of the sub-query, it is eventually stored in a system temp table. You could use the `query result cache` rather than hitting a static table.

Comment: This might be the fastest way.  Temporary tables can be surprisingly fast and can even outperform in-memory collections, as I demonstrated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22627700/409172).

Answer (score 1):

If you could do it in pure **SQL** than do it in SQL, no need of **PL/SQL**. With every SQL call in PL/SQL(or vice-versa, but less in this case) there is an overhead associated with each **context switch** between the two **engines**.

Now, having said that, if you must do it in PL/SQL, then, it is possible to reduce context switches by bulk binding the whole collection to the DML statement in one operation.

Usually a `cursor for loop` does an implicit `bulk collect limit 100` which is much better than an explicit cursor.

But, it's not just about **bulk collecting**, we are dealing with the operations we would subsequently do on the array that we have fetched incrementally. We could further improve the performance by using **FORALL** statement along with **BULK COLLECT**.

IMO, the best would be do it in pure SQL. If you really want to do it in PL/SQL, then do it as I mentioned above.

I would go with the SQL approach, and since you have the same subquery repeated, I would use `QUERY RESULT CACHE`. **Oracle 11g** introduced the **[QUERY RESULT CACHE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA617)**.

In your subquery:

```
SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ <column_list> .. <your subquery>...
```

For example,

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE */
  3         deptno,
  4         AVG(sal)
  5  FROM emp
  6  GROUP BY deptno;

Explained.
```

Let's look at the plan table output:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4067220884

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                            |     3 |    21 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  RESULT CACHE       | b9aa181887ufz5341w1zqpf1d1 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY     |                            |     3 |    21 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP                        |    14 |    98 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result Cache Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------------------

   1 - column-count=2; dependencies=(SCOTT.EMP); name="SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE */
       deptno,
       AVG(sal)
FROM emp
GROUP BY deptno"


15 rows selected.
```

Comment: thnks Latit. When you say use pure SQL, do you mean leave it as is? meaning repeting the subquery on every delete? Also, would the BULK COLLECT option be the same as the alternative I mentioned?

Comment: Yes. I might look more code, but performance wise it would be efficient. You are not hitting the same table to delete, they are all different tables. I would say, use `result cache` for the sub-query and post first call of sub-query the result would be cached.

Comment: Using a view for the subquery might help reduce the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

```
begin
  for s in (select distinct id from subquery) loop
     delete from t1 where t1.id = s.id;
     delete from t2 where t2.id = s.id;
     delete from t3 where t3.id = s.id;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

In general this is a questionable technique, as processing "row-by-row" is slower than doing multi-row operations.  But if the point is that `subquery` is very slow, this may be an improvement.

Comment: Although cursor for loop does an implicit bulk collect limit 100, row-by-row is going to be slow-by-slow for the operation on the array. Better option would be to use FORALL along with it. But, SQL would be efficient than PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a dependency between tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3` on its `id` field.

Probably you can solve this by a delete trigger on `t1` to remove entries in `t2`and `t3` as well.

I don't know exactly the affected tables of your subquery, maybe you can set an update flag (e.g. a datefield) on a further table `t0` and delete entries on `t1`, `t2` and `t3` by an update trigger on table `t0` if datefield changes.

The advantage of this solution is database consistency and pure sql.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible to use delete on multiple tables at a time.
But,one way could be to use the *sub query factoring (with clause)* .
As of now,i don't have exact answer but i think with clause might help.I will get back with exact query once i am able to devote some time.
Also,in case you have a requirement of deleting the sub query id from sub query tables as well on daily basis ,then it will be easier in sense,you can create foreign key based on on delete cascade.

Hope it helps .